# Как добавить меню на свою карту?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api, меню

Как можно добавить меню на свою карту (Google Maps JavaScript API V3)?

Мне это нужно, чтобы каждый пользователь мог рисовать линию фронта, какую-нибудь фигуру, или же ставить маркер.

Хочу, чтобы это выглядело примерно так:

[image: меню для карты]